# Javascript rgb color guessing game

Tags: javascript

Why is the first code working but not the second one? it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement."

all the squares are div and are declared in the code already.

```
var colors=[
    "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
    "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
    "rgb(255, 0, 255)",
    "rgb(25, 50, 0)",
    "rgb(2, 0, 50)",
    "rgb(255, 60, 0)"
]

var squares= document.querySelectorAll(".square");

var pickedColor=colors[3];

var colorDisplay= document.getElementById("colorDisplay");

colorDisplay.textContent= pickedColor;

for(var i=0; i<squares.length; i++){
    squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    squares[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert(this.style.backgroundColor);
    }); 


}
```

---

```
var colors=[
    "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
    "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
    "rgb(255, 0, 255)",
    "rgb(25, 50, 0)",
    "rgb(2, 0, 50)",
    "rgb(255, 60, 0)"
]

var squares= document.querySelectorAll(".square");

var pickedColor=colors[3];

var colorDisplay= document.getElementById("colorDisplay");

colorDisplay.textContent= pickedColor;

for(var i=0; i<squares.length; i++){
    squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    squares[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert(squares[i].style.backgroundColor);
    }); 

}
```

Comment: Provide HTML as well

Comment: Please click `<>` and provide a [mcve] - also you have misspelled sqaures in the second code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is the first code working but not the second one? it says
>   squares[i] is undefined whereas I have defined it.

Because by the time that event-handler is executed, `i`'s value has reached `squares.length`.

Just change `var` to `let`

```
for( let i=0; i<squares.length; i++ ){
```

Comment: @charlietfl True, but won't that be true for both the codes?

Comment: I didn't get the reason though

Comment: @AryanAgarwal Which part?

Comment: why change var to let?

Comment: @AryanAgarwal `var` doesn't let go of the bindings of the **parent lexical-environment** hence its hoisted value is retained in the **asynchronous callback handler** (event handler), however `let`'s doesn't hold on to the bindings other than its own current one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you misspelled.

```
    alert(sqaures[i].style.backgroundColor);
```

sqaures -> squares